# Change second screen resolution from command line

Tags: windows-8, command-line, resolution

Is there any way to change resolution of the **second** screen on my computer, preferably from the command line?

I've boon looking for software like this, and neither `QRes`, `HotKey Resolution Changer` and such but every single one changes resolution only of the first screen. I need just to change resolution to one a little bit lower and immedietaly restore it, just because my monitor often displays error "Out of range", which is pretty annoying doing it from monitor properties.

Comment: [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Change My Desktop Monitor Resolution via Windows PowerShell?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell.aspx)

Comment: At the same check [Display Changer](http://12noon.com/?page_id=80) it claims to have console support and it even gives examples how to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**NirCmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)'s [SetDisplay](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdisplay.html) command should do what you want:

```
nircmd setdisplay monitor:2 1600 1200 24
nircmd setdisplay monitor:name2 1600 1200 24
```

Comment: If these lines don't work for you, they may start working when you change the color depth from 24 to 32 or 16.

Comment: If you need more options (like frequency) see the free the tool I developed:  http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/